Multilevel Model in R
I have data from a study in which 19 participants (9 males, 10 females) have each completed 4 jumping conditions (BW, 20, 25, 30) whilst I have measured joint level data for the hip, knee and ankle. I would like to look at the effects of load (BW, 20, 25, 30), joint (hip, knee, ankle) and sex (male, female) on peak joint velocity, moment, power and work, and believe that a multilevel model would be appropriate.
As I am new to this type of analysis, I wondered if anyone had any specific guidance/recommendations or perhaps links to any videos or documents that may be particularly helpful for me.

Your sample size is quite small, yet complex as you've got 4 response variables. In general, I would expect these to be correlated; do you want to model them separately? A good place to start would be to visualize your data / make some graphs. For fitting LMMs (linear mixed models) in R, a popular package is {lme4}; it should be easy to find examples here.

This paper has some nice analogous examples coming from cognitive psychology. It predates lme4 but there should be some easy to find tutorials online
